# I want to make login with two table for admin and user using java swing, how can I do this?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I had written the code, but I can't login, it does not show any error(s) message(s). I don't know what's the problem. This is my code:

```
Connection kon = koneksiDB.dbStat();
        String Sql1 = "SELECT * FROM panitia_kpu WHERE nim = '"+loginNIM.getText()+"' and password = '"+loginPass.getText()+"'";
        String Sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pemilih WHERE nim = '"+loginNIM.getText()+"' and password = '"+loginPass.getText()+"'";
        try
        {
            Statement st = kon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(Sql1);
            ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(Sql2);
            if (rs1.next()){
                adminBeranda ab = new adminBeranda();
                ab.setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(false);
            }
            else if(rs2.next()){
                userBeranda ub = new userBeranda();
                ub.setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NIM atau Password anda salah!", "PERINGATAN!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }   catch (SQLException ex){

        }
```

Comment: This `ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(Sql2);` has a side effect of closing `rs1`. I don't know if your `else if` is matching any rows. This code is **vulnerable** to sql injection. So a password of `'; DROP TABLE pemilih; --` would be ***very*** unfortunate. Finally, you get no errors possibly because you silently swallow `SQLException` (don't do that). At least print the stack trace. Are your columns really named nim and password? You might need to escape password, not sure.

Comment: If you don't see any error messages and the code doesn't work hints at an `SQLException` - the only path where you ignore errors. Insert `ex.printStackTrace();` into the empty `catch` block so that you will see a message if an `SQLException` occurs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks, i will fix it asap about the vulnerable. Yes my columns name really nim and password. I already print the stack trace and it give me error 'java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed', can you help me?

Comment: @ThomasKläger it give me 'java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed' as a result, can you help me?

Comment: @NoviantoEkoBudiman Elliot explained in the very first sentence of his comment what causes that. Re-read that

Comment: @Stultuske sorry, my english is not so good, i will try to understand what he meants

Comment: @NoviantoEkoBudiman He means exactly what he said, the second ResultSet closes the first one. 

Why not have onlyone table with a column 'Admin'? You could simply check in the query if the user input has 'Yes' or something like that in the 'Admin' column and it would make your life easier.